# How to clear the Infinispan cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jboss, infinispan

In my project, we use infinispan as 2nd Level cache in combination with Hibernate 4. This is the entry from the persistence.xml

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/RuleEngine</jta-data-source>        
  <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager" value="java:jboss/infinispan/RuleEngineCache"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory"/>
  </properties>
```

What I wanted to do is to clear the cache when hitting a button on the GUI. The java code is:

```
CacheManager cm = new DefaultCacheManager();
Cache<Object, Object> c = cm.getCache();
c.clear();
```

I added this code to my web project.

But I get an exception on the first line saying `Failed to define class org.infinispan.io.ExposedByteArrayOutputStream in Module "deployment.RuleEngineWS-ear.ear.RuleEditor-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/infinispan/io/ExposedByteArrayOutputStream (Module "deployment.RuleEngineWS-ear.ear.RuleEditor-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader)`

Caused by `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/marshalling/ByteOutput` 
Caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.marshalling.ByteOutput`

The cache itself is working properly, I just have problems explicitly accessing it. I thought that I will get the one and only CacheManager if I call `new DefaulCacheManager()` but then also using this Interface is deprecated.

So if I am totally on the wrong path, how can I delete my cache then?

Infinispan 5.2.6

EDIT:
Also I tried injecting the CM by using several tries and especially the `@Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/RuleEngineCache")` annotation. But it is not injected, whether I use EmbeddedCacheManager as in the quickstart example or the deprecated CacheManager.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear Hibernate's second level cache, regardless of the caching provider, you should call up directly to Hibernate. Calling `SessionFactory.getCache().evictAllRegions` should do it, without having to get your hands dirty with Infinispan.